# NodeRed, Not able to access the variables within the nested for loops

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-cloud, node-red

I am relatively new to nodejs and my code inside the function node looks like this,

```
var temper=parseInt(msg.payload.temperature);
temp=temper;
var seconDigit=temp%10;
temp=parseInt(temp/10);
var first=temp%10;
temp=temp/10;
var count;

//msg={"payload":{"one":first,"two":seconDigit}};
//return msg;
if(msg.payload.screen=="on"){


var firstCol="*,*,#800000";
count=0;

for(var i=1;i<=2;i++){

    for(var j=1;j<=6;j++){

        if(count<first){

            firstCol=firstCol+","+i.toString()+","+j.toString()+",#C0C0C0";
            count++;
        }

    }
}

count=0;
for(var i=5;i<=6;i++){
    for(var j=1;j<=6;j++){
        if(count<seconDigit){
            firstCol+=","+i.toString()+","+j.toString()+",#C0C0C0";
            count++;
        }

    }
}
//msg={"payload":first};
//return msg;
msg={"payload":firstCol};
return msg;
}
else if(msg.payload.screen=="off"){

var firstCol="*,*,#008000";
count=0;
for(var i=1;i<=2;i++){
    for(var j=1;j<=6;j++){
        if(count<firstDigit){
            firstCol+=","+i.toString()+","+j.toString()+",#C0C0C0";
            count++;
        }

    }
}
count=0;
for(var i=5;i<=6;i++){
    for(var j=1;j<=6;j++){
        if(count<seconDigit){
            firstCol=firstCol+","+i.toString()+","+j.toString()+",#C0C0C0";
            count++;
        }

    }
}
msg={"payload":firstCol};
return msg;
}
else{
    msg={"payload":"*,*,#000000"};
    return msg;
}
```

I am unable to access the `first` and `seconDigit` variables inside the nested for loop, that part of the code is not being executed. My expected result should be one two strings. 
one is `*,*,#000000` and the other long string based on the `temp` value looks something like `*,*,.....`. But when I uncomment the couple of lines on top, they seem to work fine. What am I doing wrong and what should I change to access the values inside the for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even I had the same problem few days ago. Instead of connecting the node from which you are getting msg.payload.temperature. Just use `global.set("first",msg.payload.temperature);` 
in that node and access it using 
`temp=global.get("first");`.

So the top part of your code will be

```
temp=global.get("first");
var first=parseInt(temp/10);
var seconDigit=parseInt(temp%10);
```

Comment: By global.set() you are storing the value of the temperature to the global variable first. So you can access it from any flow in the nodered program. Alternatively you could use flow.set() to access it in the same flow.